# How to change the variable in HTML using jQuery in MVC with Java

Tags: java, html, jquery, model-view-controller, playframework

I'm new with MVC web-development using Java.

I can't really understand how I exchange variable values between HTML and .java controllers.

I have a radio buttons on my HTML, and depending on what user chooses the variable changes it's value in jQuery function. What I need is to pass this value to create a #list that is displayed in select on the same HTML page.

Here is the jQuery to get the value on radio button changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
            if (this.name=="radio-gov")
                var $gov=$('input[name=radio-gov]:checked','#myForm').val();

            console.log($gov);
        });
    });
```

Here is the code of the form:

```
<div class=" radio-group">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline formbuilder-radio">
                        <input class="form-check-input"  name="radio-gov"  access="false" id="radio-group-1650256975381-0" required="required" aria-required="true" value="65" type="radio">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-group-1650256975381-0">MIO</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline formbuilder-radio">
                        <input class="form-check-input"  name="radio-gov"  access="false" id="radio-group-1650256975381-1" required="required" aria-required="true" value="66" type="radio">
                        <label  class="form-check-label" for="radio-group-1650256975381-1">TSO</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <select class="form-control" name="select-1650256981364" id="select-gov" required>
                        #{list items:onlyParentGovAgencyList, as:'govAgency'}
                        #{if govAgency.parent != null}
                            #{if govAgency.parent.id ==66} <!--insted of 66 I want to use a variable $gov here -->
                            <option value="${govAgency.id}">

                                ${govAgency.name}
                            </option>
                            #{/if}
                        #{/if}
                    #{/list}

                    </select>
                </div>
```

This above code works, when I use the int value 66, but I need to be able to change it depending on radio button value, so I was thinking if I could use $gov variable from above jQuery?

On RequestController.java controller I have a code that produces the list:

```
public static void loadGovAgencies() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<GenericDictionaryModel> list = GenericDictionaryModel.find("removed = false and enabled = true and type = :type order by " + ((Lang.get().equals("ru"))?" nameRu" : "nameKk"))
            .setParameter("type", GenericDictionaryModel.Type.GOV_AGENCY)
            .fetch();

    List<Object[]> resultList = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("WITH RECURSIVE\n" +
            "  gov AS (\n" +
            "   SELECT t.id_,\n" +
            "          t.name_ru_||'' as group_name_ru,\n" +
            "          t.name_kk_||'' as group_name_kk,\n" +
            "          0 as level\n" +
            "   FROM ob_generic_dictionaries t\n" +
            "   where t.type_ = 'GOV_AGENCY'\n" +
            "    and t.removed_ = false\n" +
            "     and t.enabled_ = true\n" +
            "    and t.parent_ is null\n" +
            "   UNION ALL\n" +
            "   SELECT t.id_,\n" +
            "          gov.group_name_ru ||'-|-'||t.name_ru_,\n" +
            "          gov.group_name_kk ||'-|-'||t.name_kk_,\n" +
            "          gov.level + 1 as level\n" +
            "   FROM ob_generic_dictionaries t\n" +
            "      JOIN gov\n" +
            "          ON t.parent_ = gov.id_\n" +
            "    where t.type_ = 'GOV_AGENCY'\n" +
            "     and t.removed_ = false\n" +
            "     and t.enabled_ = true\n" +
            "    )\n" +
            "SELECT gov.id_, gov.level as level_, p.parent_ as has_children,  gov.group_name_ru\n" +
            "FROM gov\n" +
            "left join (Select distinct t.parent_ FROM ob_generic_dictionaries t\n" +
            "            where t.type_ = 'GOV_AGENCY'\n" +
            "             and t.removed_ = false\n" +
            "             and t.enabled_ = true) p on gov.id_ = p.parent_\n" +
            "order by " + ((Lang.get().equals("ru"))?" gov.group_name_ru" : "gov.group_name_kk"))
            .getResultList();

    List<GenericDictionaryModel> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<GenericDictionaryModel> result2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object [] row: resultList) {
        GenericDictionaryModel model = GenericDictionaryModel.findById(((BigInteger) row[0]).longValue());
        model.level = ((Integer) row[1]).intValue();

        if (row[2] != null) {
            model.hasChildren = true;
        }else{
            model.hasChildren = false;
        }
        result.add(model);

        if (model.parent != null && (model.parent.id.equals(Long.valueOf(65)) || model.parent.id.equals(Long.valueOf(66)))) {
            result2.add(model);
        }
    }

    Logger.info("loadGovAgencies.time=" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)); //        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


    

    renderArgs.put("onlyParentGovAgencyList", result2);
    renderArgs.put("parentGovAgencyList", result);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, at least maybe some docs on how do I exchange variables between HTML and .java files.

Comment: Use AJAX in your Jquery

Comment: How I do that, could you, please, tell me more?